# how to have a django form validator run on each object with ModelMultipleChoiceField rather than the queryset as a whole

Tags: django, validation, django-forms, modelform

I have a modelform which generates a series of checkboxes to add children to a parent part.  I have created a validator that checks for cyclic relationships.  I'm currently getting errors however because "proposed_child" is a queryset containing however many values the user has selected.  How do I have this validator run on each object in that queryset?

```
    def __init__(self, qs, part, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddPartToAssemblyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.part = part
        self.fields['children'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
            queryset=qs,
            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
        )

    def clean_children(self):
        proposed_child = self.cleaned_data['children']
        part = self.part
        validate_acyclic_relationship(part, proposed_child)

    class Meta:
        model = Part
        fields = ['children']
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I changed `proposed_child` to `proposed children` and changed my validator so that it iterates through the queryset it receives and validates each object in turn.

Now I have working validator but if the data is valid the form isn't returning anything in `form.cleaned_data['children']`

--edit--

needed to `return proposed_children` at the end of `clean_children`